# MySQL date difference between column3 of first row and column2 of second row

Tags: mysql, datediff

I searched for the above topic and only getting query in Oracle which uses certain keywords specific to oracle.

```
+----------+------------+--------------------+
| Agent_id | valid_from | last_modified_date |
+----------+------------+--------------------+
| 13002    | 2010-12-25 | 2011-01-03         |
| 13002    | 2011-01-03 | 2011-08-25         |
| 13002    | 2011-08-26 | 2012-12-30         |
| 13002    | 2013-01-01 | 2013-01-01         |
| 12110    | 2014-02-27 | 2014-03-03         |
| 12110    | 2014-03-25 | 2014-12-25         |
+----------+------------+--------------------+
```

I have the above table values and want to retrieve difference between `last_modified_date` of 1st row and `valid_from` date of 2nd row and likewise for the same agent(`agent id` here).

**Result table**:

```
+----------+------------+--------------------+-----------+
| Agent_id | valid_from | last_modified_date | datediff  |
+----------+------------+--------------------+-----------+
| 13002    | 2010-12-25 | 2011-01-03         |         0 |
| 13002    | 2011-01-03 | 2011-08-25         |         0 |
| 13002    | 2011-08-26 | 2012-12-30         |         1 |
| 13002    | 2013-01-01 | 2013-01-01         |         1 | 
| 12110    | 2014-02-27 | 2014-03-03         |         0 |
| 12110    | 2014-03-25 | 2014-12-25         |        22 |
+----------+------------+--------------------+-----------+
```

If there is no date for comparison on first row diff should be `0`. 
These are set of dates where the status gets changed from Y to D and to find when the agent is without any activity.

please help!!

Comment: Given that rows in an RDBMS table have no order, which one is first, and which one is second (and why?)

Answer (score 1):

Use `DATEDIFF` function.

Example for **MySQL**:

```
SELECT 
    DATEDIFF(valid_from,last_modified_date) AS 'days' 
FROM 
    table
```

[Working example on SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/7e307/2).

This will return difference in days. [Source](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_datediff)

Same for **SQL Server 2005-2012**:

```
SELECT 
    DATEDIFF(day,valid_from,last_modified_date ) AS 'days' 
FROM 
    table
```

This will return difference in days. [Source](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189794.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

Difference in days.

```
SELECT *,MIN(COALESCE(DATEDIFF(t1.valid_from, t2.last_modified_date),0)) 
FROM agents t1
LEFT JOIN agents t2 ON t1.agent_id=t2.agent_id AND t1.valid_from >= t2.last_modified_date
GROUP BY t1.agent_id, t1.valid_from
```

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/8b6ee/4

Comment: Hi mleko thanks! <br> The query works except for one date it showing incorrect values as we are using '>=' when only '>' is used it works correctly.Thanks for the immediate help. But the query is taking long time.how can i fine tune?

Comment: @user3555847 `>=` was used on purpose check this http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/28763/2 . Can you create fiddle where it gives bad result. I would add another column with `PRIMARY KEY` and add another condition in `JOIN` `t1.pk_id>t2.pk_id` Adding `INDEX` on `agent_id` might help a bit with performance

Comment: Thanks mleko. when last_modified_date and valid from are same then the minimum date is 0 pl see fiddle link above

Comment: @user3555847 right, as I said. Some unique key could help http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/468e3/1

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way to do this in MySQL is using variables:

```
select t.*
from (select t.*,
             if(agent_id = @agent_id, datediff(valid_from, @last_modified_date), 0) as datediff,
             @last_modified_date := last_modified_date,
             @agent_id := agent_id
      from table t cross join
           (select @agent_id := 0, @last_modified_date := 0) const
      order by agent_id, valid_from
     ) t;
```

You can also calculate the previous date using correlated subqueries.

By the way, those keywords that you would use in Oracle are not Oracle-specific.  They are ANSI standard functionality that MySQL does not support.

Comment: Hi Gordon, Thank you! <br>I am getting the following error. <br>You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '@last_modified_date := date_modified,
             @agent_id := agent_id
     ' at line 4 <br>

Answer (score 0):

Try this query. Change the order by clause accordingly.

I have assumed the order based on your result.

```
   select  agent_id,
    max(valid_from) as valid_from,max(last_modified_date) as last_modified_date,
    ifnull(datediff(max(valid_from),max(last_modified_date)),0)as difference

    from
    (

    select @a:=@a+1,
    case  when (@a+1)%2 = 0 then @b:=@a-2  else @b end as b  , agent_id,
    case when @a%2=0 then valid_from else 0 end as valid_from,
    case when @a%2<>0 then last_modified_date else 0 end as last_modified_date
    from table a  ,(select @a:=0,@b:=0) b
    order by agent_id desc ,valid_from

    ) a
    group by agent_id,b
```

Answer (score 0):

just change the order of fields in result a little bit

```
mysqli_multi_query('
    set @i='';
    select 
        Agent_id, if(@i='', 0,datediff(valid_from,@i)) as datediff, valid_from, (@i:=last_modified_date) as last_modified_date
    from 
        your_table'
);
```